# Multiple column layouts in renderAsPDF vf page

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css

I need to generate a pdf vf page with multiple column layouts. I read there is something in the **css 3** specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

But when I tried:

```
div.wrapper{
  columns: 2; 
  column-gap: 5mm;
  column-rule: dotted green 1mm;
}
```

in css, and a div with "wrapper" class in html,

it does not work. In output the column specification is just ignored.

**Did I miss something? Or it just not supported by vf page?**

If it is not supported, are there any alternatives?

Comment: What browser are you using? Does removing the pdf render produce the correct result?

Comment: As multicolumn is a newer CSS feature, I would suggest forgoing this for generating PDF's, and using either CSS display-table or standard HTML table tags. And another thought: are you setting the docType="HTML-5.0" attribute in your page? Since this is a newer tag I wouldn't guess the standard HTML4 doctype that Visualforce uses would work well.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that salesforce uses this to render pdfs: https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_43

It supports css 2.1